# Most accepted method of turning a table into a string

Tags: .net, vb.net, arrays

I have a table of chars.  What is the most acceptable method of turning this array into a string.

Ex:

Array:  `['a']['b']['c']`

-> abc

Thanks, any thoughts are appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either use String.Join() or if it is a character array, simply pass that as a parameter to new string constructor as below.

```
// A. 15 character array.
    char[] c = new char[15];
    c[0] = 'O';
    c[1] = 'n';
    c[2] = 'l';
    c[3] = 'y';
    c[4] = ' ';
    c[5] = 'T';
    c[6] = 'h';
    c[7] = 'e';
    c[8] = ' ';
    c[9] = 'L';
    c[10] = 'o';
    c[11] = 'n';
    c[12] = 'e';
    c[13] = 'l';
    c[14] = 'y';

    // B. 15 character string.
    string s = new string(c);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you mean you have an array of chars, and you want to concatenate its elements into a string, then it couldn't get any simpler than the Join method. Call it without any additional arguments and you should get the desired result.

Comment: It *could* get simpler than the `Join` method: How about `Dim s As String = New String(yourCharArray)`?

Comment: @Luke - I forgot about that when posting, thanks. Even so, although I agree that that is shorter, I'm not sure that it's simpler, as in, how obvious it is what it does. Anyways...

Answer (score 1):

`System.String` has a constructor which accepts an array of `char` objects.

```
Dim output as String = New String(array)
```

That's really all you need.